# CodeIgniter: Multiple Applications, how to share resources?

Tags: codeigniter

I'm building a multi-app site on CodeIgniter. I foresee some of the libraries, helpers, etc. being needed across applications. How do I share such resources between applications? It seems like I can put libraries and helpers under the `system` folder, but what if I need to share models, controllers, views, too?

Comment: It isn't possible, by default anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article helped me when developing multiple applications in the same install, I then used .htaccess for different applications and different domain names.

[Codeigniter Wiki - Multiple Applications](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Multiple_Applications/)

You would probably have to experiment with the way the folders are set up and the way calls are made in order to access shared models controllers and views.

This post [multiple sites, 1 codebase, using symlinks (with smarty)](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/56436/) might help but might not be the way you want to do it.